# IE9 Table cells full width without floating

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

Is there a way to make IE9 table cells go 100% width without resorting to using floats.
Using `display:block` is sufficient on other browsers but not for IE9, floats do work but with complex nested tables it causes IE9 to crash when switching between media queries.

Comment: Why? That behavior defeats the purpose of the table layout.

Comment: You could try setting the adjacent cells to display: none, so that the one visible goes to 100%.

Comment: If you need a table cell to ocuppy the entire row use colspan. If this is not na option, you are using a table for the wrong pourpose.

Comment: The purpose is to achieve a stacked presentation of table markup by using CSS only, so it can be viewed in smaller screens. There are examples of this already but they use floats which for some reason are causing a browser crash on my markup. See example with floats: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/tables/table-reflow.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't test on IE9 but you should **also** set `display: block` on elements related to a table like `table`, `tbody` and `tr`.
That should help, please give feedback if it doesn't :)

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/NAqLX/1/embedded/result/ and http://jsfiddle.net/NAqLX/embedded/result/ fail on IE8 (while working on Firefow, at least) so maybe it doesn't work on IE9 either
EDIT2: after asking my colleague who wanted a few `tr` or `tbody` going along (displayed as inline-block), it seems it's a big no on IE8/9